# split at the first space in a string

Tags: php, split

I have a string like this:

> *red yellow blue*

and I want to get an array like this :

> Array (
>       [0] => red
>       [1] => yellow blue )

how to split at the first space in a string ?
my code doesn't work

```
<?php
$str = "red yellow blue";
$preg = preg_split("/^\s+/", $str);
print_r($preg);
?>
```

please help me.

Answer (score 117):

Use `explode` with a limit:

```
$array = explode(' ', $string, 2);
```

Just a side note: the 3rd argument of `preg_split` is the same as the one for `explode`, so you could write your code like this as well:

```
$array = preg_split('#\s+#', $string, 2);
```

---

*References:*

> [PHP: explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
>
> [PHP: preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

Comment: For the curious, the third parameter is the max number of elements in the array, and the last element will take everything left over.

Answer (score 16):

```
<?php
$string = "red yellow blue";
$result = explode(" ", $string, 2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

just explode it

Answer (score 4):

You can use explode function like this

```
print_r(explode(' ', $str, 2));
```

It will set a limit. Check more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), but if you aren't 100% sure you'll have the same # of spaces (explosions) every time, you can use [ltrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) to remove the first word and space

```
<?php
$full='John Doe Jr.';
$full1=explode(' ', $full);
$first=$full1[0];
$rest=ltrim($full, $first.' ');
echo "$first + $rest";
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

function splitName($name) {
$parts = explode(' ', $name);
return array(
'firstname' => array_shift($parts),
'lastname' => join(' ', $parts)
);
}

Answer (score -6):

You can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) this way:

```
  $stringText  = "red yellow blue";
  $colours = explode(" ", $stringText);
  echo $colours[0]; //red 
  echo $colours[1]; //yellow
  echo $colours[2]; //blue
```

You can also get all the elements of $colours by foreach Loop, but in this case explode is better

Comment: This would split the string at _every_ space - the question asks for a split at the _first_ space only.